# When using Electron, what is the best way to design the HTML/CSS layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, electron

Do most people just manually type the values in? Or is there some type of UI builder similar to Android/iOS drag and drop UI builder? Like I know even most websites now a days don't have you manually type in the HTML instead using some type of site builder.

Answer (score 1):

You can design your electron application using angular.

- Angular
- Angular material

If you want to do something that is simple, using those frameworks will make your program grow the complexity of it, so it might not we worth it. However, if your program and its internal state is complex enough,using angular its likely to save you up a lot of time and effort, and will simplify your development. I can tell that Electron is angular compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no 'drag and drop' UI builder for electron apps, you have to type HTML, CSS and JavaScript. But there is a workaround which you can use to generate html template file and css.

You can use any drag and drop website builder, like WordPress, squarespace etc. Download the static assets(css, html) generated by the builder and then add JavaScript code manually to add functionality of your app.

Again, this is only a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There's no drag and drop UI builder for Electron currently, but you can use [PhotonKit](http://photonkit.com/) library to build OSX-like user interfaces

Comment: Browsing this framework's components, it feels like Mac. Will the component look fancy on windows or linux?